# Overflow-x: hidden doesn't work in mobile browsers. What should I do?

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

Overflow-x: hidden doesn't work in mobile Google Chrome. On a laptop, the layout of the norms looks like in developer mode too. And on mobile phones there are problems ...
What should I do about it?

Comment: Show me your code in CSS and Html!

Comment: Sounds like you have a media query removing it, please create a [mcve] otherwise we cannot help you